# Running a python script (which crawl scrapy spiders) from another python script

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrapy project with two spiders. Also I created test.py (in this scrapy project) to crawl spiders

code :

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

process.crawl('nameofspider1', domain='domain')
process.crawl('nameofspider2', domain='domain')

process.start()
```

and it works fine.

The problem is when I want to run this script (test.py) from another python script, then I got

> KeyError: 'Spider not found: `nameofspider1`'

The code of the second python script:

```
import os

os.system('python C:\Users\Adam\nameofproject\test.py')
```

Thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with path. I had to add:

```
import os
os.chdir(r'project_path')
```

Answer (score 1):

I do this to run my spider.

```
import os
import subprocess

os.chdir('projectname')
subprocess.call(
    ['scrapy', 'crawl', 'spidername']
)
```